# Cannot find name 'Input'.ts(2304)

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I wanted to use angular data-binding and the Input decorator to get input values from a component to another given child component.

I have a minimal example to show you how i wanted to accomplish this task:

**Parent template:**

```
<h4>Passing value of input element to child component:</h4>
<input [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="name = $event">
<p>{{name}}</p>
<hello [name]="name"></hello>
```

**Parent component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = '';
}
```

**Child component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h4>Passed : "{{ name }}" to child component!</h4>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

this seems to work fine enough on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pggcbd

But my Local typescript compiler responds:

`Cannot find name 'Input'.ts(2304)`

and marks the `@Input()` decorators. any ideas?

Comment: You might have imported the wrong Class.

Comment: To better clarify the question, add full files with import declarations, please.

Comment: Your [snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pggcbd) works fine to me, or am missing something

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's just missing or incorrect import.

Add the import to `import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'`